# Importing Android-Download-Manager library results "failed to resolve"?

Tags: android, github, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to add [Android-Download-Manager](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/2131)  library to my project but after sync project error message says -`Failed to resolve:com.github.majidgolshadi:Android-Download-Manager-Pro:8772a374e0`

**adding library like this**

```
 repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
}

compile 'com.github.majidgolshadi:Android-Download-Manager-Pro:8772a374e0'
```

but error comes always.

**i have also tried by Downloading library and importing to android studio and also tried using File>New>Import Module but nothing helps**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android-Download-Manager-Pro is a android-app project, not library. You can fork it and to change it to library-type project, or download classes froim it and add it all into your current project.

You can check libraries in [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io) by "Look up" button - for releases/commits near version you can see "Get it" status, if library is available.

Comment: what should i do here. what is best way?

Comment: I think, easy way, for you, put all files from https://github.com/majidgolshadi/Android-Download-Manager-Pro/tree/master/com/golshadi/majid into uour project

Comment: ok i will do this. can i simply paste library files to my project or any other way ?

Comment: Yes, you can simply paste library files. After this, please, check package name in pasted files.

Comment: did i need to change package name of library to my project package name

Comment: yes, you need, if package name of your application is different than com.golshadi.majid :)